# Why is Last Modified and Modified having different data?

Tags: jsom, query

I am trying to retrieve data using the JSOM model,
and trying to figure out the last modified date of a SharePoint List Item,

Its really strange when I am trying to retrieve the Last Modfied Date from the item

```
OneListItem.get_item('Last_x0020_Modified'); => Shows Created Date
OneListItem.get_item('Modified'); => Shows Modified Date
```

My question is if, the option 2 is already working, why does 1 even return the data and if it actually does, why does it return the created Date?

Seems to be a bug Isnt IT?

Comment: I think it's list items versioning related but I couldn't understand how it really works.

Comment: Is Last Modified a user added or calculated column? "Modified" is the expected name.

Comment: Last Modified and Modified are both Date type columns.

Answer (score 0):

Last_x0020_Modified seems to be a custom column and not a internal, automatically updated, one like 'Modified'. You would have to look at how that column is populated.